# How to custom an ImageView with URL?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview, picasso

With my android application I'm trying to custom an image view with URL, and I keep getting an error that my ImageView object is null, the error:

> ```
> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: tvImage must not be null"
> ```

I tried to use Picasso library and to use Async. With both I'm getting the error and I don't understand why.

There's my code using Async:

The call on onCreate:

```
DownloadImage(findViewById(R.id.tvImage)).execute(FeedAdapter.imageUrl)
```

This is the class for download the image with the URL:

```
private class DownloadImage(val imageView: ImageView) : AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
    private val TAG = "DonloadImage"

    /** Methods: */
    override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result)

    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): Bitmap {
        Log.d(TAG, "doingBackground: starts with ${url[0]}")
        val rssFeed = downloadImage(url[0])

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(rssFeed)
    }


    private fun downloadImage(urlPath: String?): InputStream {
        return URL(urlPath).openStream()
    }
}
```

There's my code using Picasso:

```
 if (tvImage.drawable != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(FeedAdapter.imageUrl).into(tvImage)
    }
```

This is my layout file include the imageView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="NBA Live Mobile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvArtist"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"
    tools:text="Electronic Arts" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSummary"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvArtist" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tvImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvArtist"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: please can I see your `layout` file and the `onCreate/onCreateView` of your `activity/fragment`

Comment: Please check if you are initializing tvImage correctly, for the Picasso code.

Comment: I added the layout in xml for the activity. The onCreate function has unrelevant other code which is part of the application so I didn't include it.@Fornoth Thomas

Comment: @RaviKumar how should I need to initialize this image view?

Comment: @erezlev13 add this line **tvImage = findViewById(R.id.tvImage)** in the onCreate function after the line setContentView. it should work.